# LED Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want create one simple code that turn on the light of the led of my phone(nexus 5), when I press one button in my app!
I tried with this code that I've take on the web! But don't work!

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
                Notification notif = new Notification();
                notif.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
                notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
                notif.ledOnMS = 100;
                notif.ledOffMS = 100;

            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**

I tried with this to see is the code works, but the app crash when I press the button!

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                int s=100;
                manager.goToSleep(s);


                Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                        .setLights(0xff0000, 4000, 100)
                        .build();

            }
        });
```

I've add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<user-permission android:name= "android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

Comment: I think this only works with the screen off.

Comment: some phones let the led works only if the screen is off (Galaxy S4 example)

Comment: how can I turn off the screen and see if the code works?

Comment: not the phone, the screen.

Comment: yea sorry! the screen! :)

Comment: just press the power button like you always do... but you mean with code?

Comment: when I press the button nothing happens because the screen is on, if I have not misunderstood, So the simple so the most simple mode to see if the code works is to turn off the screen, but how I can do this?

Comment: what do you mean you dont know how to turn the screen off?

Comment: yes, I don't know how turn off the screen and see if the code works!

Comment: PRESS THE POWER BUTTON!!

Comment: -.- if I push the power button how i can press the button in my app!?!?!? -.-

Comment: this is not a hard concept, you press the button in your app then press the power button...

Comment: the code work when I press the button!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

          Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
          .setAutoCancel(false)          
          .setLights(0xff0000, 4000, 100)
          .build();
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps.